# Managing Sessions between ASP.NET Pages and WebAPI Controller

Tags: asp.net, session, asp.net-web-api

I have **ASP.NET** application (not **MVC**), with **WEPAPI** controllers.

we are using these controllers to share data between asp pages using **ajax** request.

when i logged into the system, i store the username in a **session**, but while i trying to check the value of this session in the controller, its value i null regardless if user is logged in or not.

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["Username"] = "admin";
```

How can i use the same session between **controller** and **asp.net** page?

Comment: An API shouldn't change its responses based on a session. Try rewriting it to something stateless and require the needed information in the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET Web API does not support sessions out of the box.
As in your case ,if you are running your ASP.NET Web API within the ASP.NET run time you can enable session support globally by adding below in the Global.asax

```
protected void Application_PostAuthorizeRequest() 
{  

HttpContext.Current.SetSessionStateBehavior(SessionStateBehavior.Required);

}
```

Comment: thanks, it works. does this statement has any side effect regarding session management?

Comment: @GeorgianCitizen , Nope, This will have no side effects.

Comment: @GeorgianCitizen . But ideally you should not be depending on session in HTTP based api resource.HTTP is stateless,after all . But we end up with pragmatism as per the project demands !